# Как подключить cppcoro в cmake?

Tags: cmake, c++20

Как подключить cppcoro в cmake?

Comment: какую именно библиотеку cppcoro Вы пытаетесь подключить?

Comment: @KoVadim, а до нее нужно указывать путь вручную? Нет cmake конуструкции для этого, как к примеру с бустом?

Comment: boost - это очень известная и популярная библиотека. О ней все знают. Что за библиотека cppcoro - я не уверен. гугл показал несколько репозиториев. Скорее всего Вам нужно будет самостоятельно её "cmake-фицировать". Или просто выбросить cmake.